# MMS Stopped working in my Nokia Lumia 520

Tags: lumia-520, mms

MMS stopped working. The service provider is Ultra-mobile. Went to 2 shops to fix it, they said buy a new phone instead because your phone is not compatible. But it was before! Any help?

I can't send and receive any media. It says:

> Can't send: Media content in this message.

I bought this phone on Amazon.com, it was unlocked but with AT&T features on it. I don't have access point in settings. I go through **mobile+sim** > **edit MMS APN** > **APN-wholesale**, username-blank, password-blank, authentication type-PAP, WAP-blank, MMSC port-8080, maximum MMS size-blank.

Don't know what it should be. Customer service didn't help + messed up the internet.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean when you say MMS stopped working. Are you unable to receive or send or both? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: The phone would be compatible, and it sounds like they're trying to sell you something you don't need, but what have you tried to resolve the issue? Have you checked or changed the messaging settings at all? Have you called your Telco, to ask them to push the settings down to you?

Comment: Try this link to install Access Point on your phone:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/access-point/ce3895c7-01d0-4daf-a4c3-25c10463942d

Comment: APN-wholesale should just be wholesale according to the settings I have.  Like I said I don't know if they're right.

Comment: Here are links to a bunch of Nokia apps in the Windows store.  They say they're for WP 8.  I think they're still valid though:

http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Pool-of-Knowledge/Nokia-Windows-Phone-8-App-Updates/td-p/1640082

Answer (score 2):

Is your phone supplied by Ultra-mobile?  Either way, you may need to tweak your APN settings.  In settings > access point

I found some settings for Ultra-mobile on this site, I have no idea if they work:

http://www.techlivewire.com/1839/internet-apn-settings-for-ultra-mobile.html

### Here's the settings:

Android settings for Ultra Mobile.  These should also work on Windows Phone and iPhone

ultra mobile apn settings

- Name – Ultra
- APN – wholesale
- Proxy – blank
- Port – blank
- Username – blank
- Server – blank
- MMSC – http://wholesale.mmsmvno.com/mms/wapenc
- MMS Proxy – blank

MMS Port – blank
MCC – 310
MNC – 260
Authentication Type – blank
APN Type- default,supl,mms

Comment: Could you include the relevant info in your answers just in case this link goes dead in the future?